# Issue with my Brute Force Algorithm in C++ Language

Tags: c++, brute-force

I came across a question where i'm to create a program that has a function that generates random password using the ASCII table( generating random numbers using srand from 0 to 256 and then typecasting them into characters.), another function to display the generated password. Then another function to crack the generated password using brute force method . The function that generates the password works fine but the issue I have is with the function that cracks the password.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void Generate_Pass(char pass[5])
{
    int seed = time(NULL);
    srand(seed);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        pass[i] = rand()%256;
    }
}

void Display_Pass(char pass[5])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cout << pass[i] << " ";
    }
}

void Cracked(char cracked[5], char pass[5])
{
    do
    {
        for(int a = 0; a < 5; a++){
            int b = rand()%256;
            cracked[a] = char(b);
        }
    }while(cracked[0] != pass[0]);
    do
    {
        for(int a = 0; a < 5; a++){
            int b = rand()%256;
            cracked[a] = char(b);
        }
    }while(cracked[1] != pass[1]);
    do
    {
        for(int a = 0; a < 5; a++){
            int b = rand()%256;
            cracked[a] = char(b);
        }
    }while(cracked[2] != pass[2]);
    do
    {
        for(int a = 0; a < 5; a++){
            int b = rand()%256;
            cracked[a] = char(b);
        }
     }while(cracked[3] != pass[3]);
    do
    {
        for(int a = 0; a < 5; a++){
            int b = rand()%256;
            cracked[a] = char(b);
        }
    }while(cracked[4] != pass[4]);
}

void Display_Cracked(char cracked[5])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cout <<  cracked[i] << " ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    char pass[5];
    Generate_Pass(pass);
    cout << "The Password is: ";
    Display_Pass(pass);
    cout << "\n";
    char cracked[5];
    Cracked(cracked, pass);
    cout << "The cracked password is: ";
    Display_Cracked(cracked);
}
```

That's the code that I've worked on, but whenever I run the brute force function doesn't work as it's supposed to be.

Comment: Do not use magic numbers.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please [read how to write an effective question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, please keep it concise to the problem you're having and avoid using screenshots (copying error messages is preferred). Feel free to edit your question to improve it.

Comment: Your for loops insert random numbers into the array position but only the last of those random numbers is ever checked.

Comment: When searching for the "correct" character start at the first character and work up.  No reason to use a random letter there.  And don't change `cracked[0]` once you've found it.

Comment: Why do you use random numbers in brute force method at all? Just go through all possible char[5] arrays.Your code is wrong because each for cycle generate a guess. Then the first while cycle just compares first char and if it matches then the second for cycle immediately overwrites the first guess. Either change `int a=0` for other cycles, or just use one while where the condition is full match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in your `Cracked` method, you are looping over all five indices conditional on only one index. You do this five times. It takes an average of 256 attempts to match the correct character. This results in generation and assignment of about 5*5*256=6400 integers, which is more work than you need.

The problem with your code is that you are assigning to all five indices in each `do while` loop. Then whatever correct character you figured out in the previous loop will be overwritten by random data in the next loop so that only the last character is correct. Below is a tweaked implementation that fixes these problems.

```cpp
void Cracked(char cracked[5], char pass[5]) {
  for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
    do {
      int b = rand() % 256;
      cracked[a] = char(b);
    } while(cracked[a] != pass[a]);
  }
}
```

Since the `for` loop is on the outside now, it will try random stuff until it figures out a character and then move on to the next character without touching any other characters.

You will also notice that using a for loop results in much less code which was mostly the same. Generally, if you find yourself copy-pasting code, it means you should be using a loop or function or some other construct to avoid the extra code or to have the compiler generate it for you. This makes your code much easier to maintain. For instance if you wanted to replace the `rand` function used in each `do while` loop, you would have to replace it only once rather than five times.

Also, in this case it would probably be better to try all possible values separately rather than random values (e.g. with a `for` loop). I will let you figure that part out.

Answer (score -1):

A [Brute Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search) solution is one which is:

> Systematically enumerating all possible candidates for the solution and checking whether each candidate satisfies the problem's statement

This means that you'd need to generate all possible combinations of the given length. (You can never guarantee you've done that using `rand`.) As [mentioned by @Slava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52668733/issue-with-my-brute-force-algorithm-in-c-language#comment92267262_52668733) you shouldn't use magic numbers so we'll call this length:

```
#define LENGTH 5
```

From there you can just do a simple nested `while`-loop:

```
string Cracked(const char* pass) {
    string result('\0', LENGTH);

    while(!equal(cbegin(result), cend(result), pass)) {
        if(result.back() < numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()) {
            ++result.back();
        } else {
            for(auto it = rbegin(result); it != rend(result); *it++ = '\0') {
                if(*it < numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()) {
                    ++(*it);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```